# Terminal equivalent for gui popup windows in python

Tags: python, terminal, notifications, popup

I am going to write simple "to do list" app in python. One of the features will be possibility to configure notifications/reminders for tasks. If user will be using GUI I am going to use some popup windows, but what if he runs the app in the terminal, without any GUI? What would be the best equivalent for that? Is there a possibility to somehow notify the user?

I will be thankful for any guidance or at least direction, I tried searching for all variants of "terminal/console/text" + "notifications/popups" but I did not find anything interesting...

Comment: Terminal IO is like a conversation. The user types something, the program    prints something in reply and so on. So if your program needs to display a message, just print it to the screen. Of course you're to do list will scroll, so you have to redisplay it, after clearing the screen if you wish. Of course you could write a kind of character based 'GUI', buffering your output to an array and redisplaying that. But in that case you're better of using a real GUI then (TkInter comes with Python).

Comment: That's probably a good idea, but I had in mind real notifications/reminders, which is something that appear on desired time. For example, user defined reminder at 5 p.m. with some text. On GUI that is not a problem - program working in the background will display popup window with this text. How to deal with it in terminal environment?

Comment: The easiest thing is to have an endless loop (event loop) as the basis of your program. In this loop you read input (per key), write output (per character) and inspect the system clock to find out if you have to do something special, like printing a reminder and sounding a bell char (char (7) I think. That's also how a real GUI does it, with an event loop. An alternative is using multithreading or timer callbacks.